# Linux project work

Tags: linux, opensource-projects

I am a b.tech 2nd yr. student from Motilal Nehru National Institute of Technology - Allahabad.

I am currently doing linux system administration course in this summer. I want to do a project work related to same also, but I don't have any idea regarding the topics on which projects can be done.

Can anyone suggest some topics or any link regarding this?

Answer (score 3):

The best thing is to find something that YOU are interested in. Find a need that you have that isn't met by existing software or where the existing software could use improvement. Get involved in those projects.

Consider looking at the Google summer of code system as one motivational way to be involved in an open source project you are interested in.

Also find out what people in your area are working on and see if you can get a local team together. You'll learn more from each-other that way.

Answer (score 1):

Caleb gives good advice. what sorts of skills or interests do you have at your disposal ? This may shape your decision. What would you consider a "project" ?

If its a programming related task, one thing i like to do is trawl sourceforge or similar for projects in the "planning" stage, where you can see the project is basically dead, and take this through to a finished project.

If its a sys admin task like learning something new, you can try to deploy some real world scenarios in a visualised setup, such as load balancing or such.

Perhaps get involved with an open source project or distribution and get active in the community, you'll find people who need advice and help, some of these may have ideas for tasks.